# tiny mce valid elements end tag

Tags: tinymce

I have a custom tag like this:
`<content name="Home" />`

When I click the Html button of the TinyMCE it was replaced with

`<content name="Home"></content>`

Currently my settings are: `valid_elements: "content[name]"`

What should I put in the `valid_elements` variable so that the tag will will be:
`<content name="Home" />`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not perfectly sure, but i think this issue is not to be solved easily.
I do not think that you can configure this behavior because it is browser related and not tinies fault. Looks like the browser treats your custom html element like an html element with an opening and a closing part on default, even though you want to have a single part html element like a br-tag. The only way - i see - is to get the browser to accept your custom thlm elment as one part html element, which i do not know how to do.

Comment: Thanks, I decided to use {content:Home} instead of using tag.